# Docker-compose can't see files in mounted volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I recently started to learn docker and docker-compose and i've decided to dockerize small python script just for practise. The script is taking files from specified input directory, processing them and saving to specified output directory. Input and Output directories on the host machine must be mounted as a volumes inside the container. But it turns out that inside the container my script can't see any files inside mounted diretories.

My OS is Windows 10, i'm using Docker Desktop with WSL2.

The structure of my project direcory looks like this:

```
-./src
  -app.py
  -Dockerfile
-docker-compose.yaml
```

Here is the Dockerfile for building image of my script:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

I'm building it with:

```
docker build -t laz2pcd .
```

And here is the Docker-compose file to start the container with mounted volumes:

```
services:
  laz2pcd:
    image: laz2pcd
    volumes:
      - /mnt/c/laz_test:/var/data_in
      - /mnt/c/pcd_test:/var/data_out
    environment:
      - INTENSITY=TRUE
      - OFFSET_X=0
      - OFFSET_Y=0
      - OFFSET_Z=0
```

The container works without any errors, but does nothing and logs from the script telling me that there are no files to process.

Turns out, that if i move directories on the host machine to the directory with the docker-compose.yaml file and change volumes as such:

```
volumes:
      - ./src:/app
      - ./laz_test:/var/data_in
      - ./pcd_test:/var/data_out
```

then it will finaly see and process my files.

This behavior is blowing my mind and i honestly can't figure out what's going on. Why can't i use any folder on my host machine except those which are in my project folder? And why do i need to mount `./src:/app`?
I will be gratefull for your clarification.

Comment: Under _Settings > Resources > File Sharing_ of your Docker desktop application, you can configure the folders that can be used as bind mounts. Your configuration is probably missing those folders.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the issue on Linux, actually it working on my end.

My docker compose file:

```
volumes:
  # - ./frontend/:/app
  # - /app/node_modules/
  - /home/ajay/work/tut/python:/var/data_in
```

My container:

```
root@4c641a10fa27:/var/data_in# pwd
/var/data_in
root@4c641a10fa27:/var/data_in# ls
class_variable.py  import_inside_docker
root@4c641a10fa27:/var/data_in# touch test_newfile
root@4c641a10fa27:/var/data_in# ls
class_variable.py  import_inside_docker  test_newfile
root@4c641a10fa27:/var/data_in#
```

My host path

```
(base) ajay@G15:~/work/tut/python$ pwd
/home/ajay/work/tut/python
(base) ajay@G15:~/work/tut/python$ ls
class_variable.py  import_inside_docker  test_newfile
(base) ajay@G15:~/work/tut/python$
```